# Return to a particular job in the jobs list

Tags: shell, process-management, job-control, jobs

If I have the following jobs running in a shell

```
-> % jobs -l
[1]    83664 suspended  nvim
[2]    84330 suspended  python
[3]    84344 suspended  python
[4]    84376 suspended  nvim
[5]  - 84701 suspended  python
[6]  + 84715 suspended  python
```

How can i return to the nth job, suppose I want to return to job 4, or job 1, how can I do that without having to kill all those which are before it?

Comment: To return to job 4, try: `fg %4`

Comment: Presumably you suspended each of these jobs, either from the foreground by Ctrl-Z, or from the background by kill -STOP pid or kill -TSTP pid in the background. (My Bash says Stopped -- I'm not sure what 'suspended' actually means: it may be that a background job attempted to read from the terminal.) fg %4 brings job 4 back to running as the foreground. bg %4 sets it running in the background. You can have a maximum of one foreground job.

Comment: add as an answer and i'll accept - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return to job 4, run:

```
fg %4
```

The command `fg` tells the shell to move job `%4` to the foreground.  For more information, run `help fg` at the command prompt.

When you want to suspend the job you are working on, run `bg`.  For more information, run `help bg` at the command prompt.

For more detail than you'd likely want to know, see the section in `man bash` entitled `JOB CONTROL`.